# Cocos2d-X V-3.6, WP8.1 Resources duplication issue in VisualStudio 2013

Tags: c++11, windows-phone-8.1, cocos2d-x

I have added "hd" and "sd" graphics support in my game, it works fine on Android and IOS, but when i build it for WP8.1, it gives the following error:

> Error  14  error APPX1101: Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path 'test_image.png'. Source files:
>
> D:\Cocos2d-x\MyGame\Resources\hd\test_image.png
>
> D:\Cocos2d-x\MyGame\Resources\sd\test_image.png

If I add only a single file i.e either its in "sd" or "hd" directory, it runs fine. but i need both to support various screen sizes

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got this sorted out.
Actually you dont need to add those folders & files into visual studio too.

> I am not adding those files into visual studio, just building direct and its working fine now